# Making HTML Element populate with query from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make the html element

```
<p id="userInfo"></p>
```

have the value of the username that was user to login in the session. I have the following variable set to contain the variable that holds the username and works this works for logging in.

```
$_SESSION['globalUser'] = $_POST['resultUser'];
```

I currently am attempting to set the userInfo element with

```
<script>document.getElementById(userInfo).value='<?php echo $_SESSION['globalUser']?>'</script>
```

This script is causing the error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

When I open the developer tools and click the error it shows

```
<script>document.getElementById(userInfo).value='<br />
```

I also using the following statement to transfer the session across pages

```
<?php $session_value=(isset($_SESSION['id']))?$_SESSION['id']:''; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

This is currently my query

```
$sqlUser = "SELECT `teacher_username` FROM `teacher` WHERE `teacher_username`='$user'";
$sqlPass = "SELECT `password` FROM `teacher` WHERE `password`='$pass'";
$resultUser = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlUser);
$resultPass = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlPass);
$textUser = $resultUser->fetch_assoc();
$textPass = $resultPass->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['globalUser'] = $_POST[$textUser['teacher_username']];
```

Comment: Try this: <script>document.getElementById('userInfo').innerHTML="<?php echo $_SESSION['globalUser']; ?>";</script> Use double quotes if there are nested quotes. userInfo ID needs to be in quotes. End you JS and your PHP statements with a semi-colon ;

Comment: That produced the same error as before

Comment: Why are you doing it with JS instead of `<p id="userInfo"><?php echo $_SESSION['globalUser']; ?></p>`?

Comment: It looks like you have `<br />` in `$_SESSION['globalUser']`.

Comment: You also have a newline in the variable. JavaScript doesn't allow newlines in string literals, that's what's causing the syntax error.

Comment: Barmar, your suggestion gave me an error of "Undefined variable: _SESSION"

Comment: That will happen if you don't have `session_start()` at the beginning.

Comment: You need quotes around `userInfo`. And `<p>` elements don't have a value, that's only for user input elements. You need to assign to `innerText`.

Comment: Does the <?php $session_value=(isset($_SESSION['id']))?$_SESSION['id']:''; ?> not take care of that?

Comment: That takes care of it for the `$session_value` variable, but doesn't have anything to do with `$_SESSION['globalUser']`

Comment: I tried starting the session and using the <p id="userInfo"><?php echo $_SESSION['globalUser']; ?></p> , it didn't produce an error or result.

Comment: Your password query seems wrong. What if they enter the password for a different teacher? You also shouldn't store plaintext passwords in the database, you should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: `$textUser['teacher_username']` will be the same as `$user`, why do you need to fetch it from the DB?

Comment: That's how I compare them for login. I also haven't added security yet, I'm waiting until this is working. This is also for learning not production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the ID `userinfo`, otherwise it will be used as a variable rather than a literal.

You should assign to `innerText` rather than `value`; only user input elements have a value.

To convert PHP values to JavaScript literals, the safest way is to use `json_encode()`. It will add quotes and any necessary escaping.

```
<script>document.getElementById('userInfo').innerText=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['globalUser']); ?>;</script>
```

Comment: <script>document.getElementById(userInfo).innerText=null;</script>

Comment: calendar.php:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the quotes.

Comment: So the session variable is not filled in. Make sure you have `session_start();` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: where do the quotes go? I have <?php session_start();?> in the head

Comment: Make sure `session_start()` is before ANY HTML is output. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: it is, I added quotes around userInfo and no longer have errors, just not the output

Comment: I added text between the p tags and it gets overwritten with a blank.

Comment: Are you still getting `null` for the session variable?

Comment: I don't think so, I cant find it any more

Comment: So what do you see now after `document.getElementById('userInfo').innerText=`?

Comment: It is still null

Comment: I have edited the OP to contain how I'm getting the data.